# Why is this JavaScript regex slow?

Tags: javascript, regex

```
var email = '[John Smith] <johnsmith@gmail.com>';

var re1 = /.*<+(.*)+>.*/;
var re2 = /.*\[+(.*)+\].*/;

var address = email.replace(re1, "$1");
var name = email.replace(re2, "$1");
```

I am finding that the 2nd regex (to get the name) runs super slow. but the first one is fine. Why is this and is there a better way to get the strings that I need?

Comment: How do you measure that?

Comment: Also, as those do not change the result in this particular case, I don't see the point in `+` symbols in your regex

Comment: Use for function and operate by chars

Comment: It gets run on a click event and it freezes up my browser for a few seconds. If I have the 2nd one commented out it runs instantly.

Comment: Oh wow http://jsperf.com/2-regexes So unexpected to me

Comment: @zerkms: That is weird. Maybe it's because of the unnecesary `+` with escaped characters? Dunno...

Comment: @Lindrian: yep, but they are identical except of only couple of literals `<` vs `\[` which shouldn't change the performance **that** dramatically :-S 1M times difference is inordinary thing

Comment: I'd assume, since the `<` and especially the `>` are at the end of the string, the first expression has to do fewer backtracking than the second one. Just switch `<>` and `[]` and test it: http://jsperf.com/2-regexes/2. Generally it's best to avoid `.*`.

Comment: @Felix Kling: but not on a 20 characters string

Comment: What is the performance of a regex such as this `re2 = /\[([^\]]*)\]/;`, `name = email.match(re2)[1];`

Comment: @zerkms: I agree that the difference is dramatic, but what other thing than backtracking could it be? In the second expression, the first two `.*` basically have both to go through the *whole* string to find a match. In the first expression, only the first `.*` has to go through *half* of the string... crappy engine maybe (no idea)?

Comment: Also, if you're in the global namespace it is a very bad idea to `var name`, because `'name' in window`.

Comment: @Felix Kling: I'm not sure, but for ~20 char string and ~10 char regex I'd never expect something like that. Checked in php - it's reproducible there as well - http://ideone.com/JTtPMB with about 1k times difference :-S

Comment: @zerkms: I have explained it thoroughly in my answer. I hope everyone here learned something today.

Comment: @Lindrian: I understand the issue. Though I couldn't predict it before running the test. I doubt anyone could. This is the first time I see so short regex on so short data is so slow.

Comment: @zerkms: it comes with experience. I could immediately spot it. You see it on the typically bad construct.

Comment: Btw, if you want to get a better understanding of regular expressions, have a look at: http://shop.oreilly.com/product/9780596528126.do.

Comment: Haha thanks everyone. Yep obviously I know next to nothing about regular expressions. I copy pasted something else then modified. Maybe I should have asked where to go to start learning regex instead :P

Comment: @DougMacKenzie: the quiz on http://regex101.com/quiz/ is quite nice. Otherwise the book linked in the comment above is awesome, too.

Comment: This is perfectly clear question, with a great answer with a specific, testable improvement that resolves the issue.  Another good example of bad moderation on SE. *sigh*

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The reason your regular expressions are slow is because they are *horribly written*.

Now, lets go on to say why they are bad.

Your first expression has a *bunch* of unnecessary tokens. Such as the leadning and trailing `.*` - they make no difference. Secondly, you have quantified the `<` 0 to inf times. Why? Are you wanting to match `<<<<<<<<email>`? or `email>`? Lastly, you have quantified a repeating group. This is horrible because

1. A quantified capturing group will overwrite itself
2. Due to the statement above, it makes no sense to use a capturing group, thus it uses unnecessary resources.

Alright, that's the first expression. The second one is even worse, even though you just switched `<>` for `[]`. Why you might ask? I'll tell you why. **BECAUSE IT DOES NOT MATCH**. Why is this so bad you might ask? Because it generates what we call *catastrophic backtracking*. Why does it do this you might wonder? I'll tell you why:

`.*` Will try to match as much as possible. In fact, at first, it will consume the entire string. Obviously that fails, so it backtracks a bunch of times until it can match the first `[`. Awesome, now the engine has found a match at the first position of the string for the literal `[` (thus making the `.*` match nothing). Now the next token, `.*` will again match everything due to its greedy nature. This does not work, so the engine backtracks. It will keep trying to do this until it matches the string. Problem is, it never will. Because your greedy quantifier is surrounded by a quantified group that requires 1 or more matches.

Now, how do you fix this? Well, you could simply remove the `+` from behind the group. That would fix it. Your regular expressions would still be horrible, but they would not cause the engine to backtrack a million times. How can we improve it even further? By using negated character classes.

`/\[([^]]+)\] <([^>]+)>/`

View a demo of the regular expression over here: http://regex101.com/r/wS2jN0

If you had used regex101.com to begin with you would have noticed the backtracking problem immediately: http://regex101.com/r/vB8xB0

Comment: I can't +1 this answer because of the first line. That the reason is the backtracking is correct, though.

Comment: To get the best possible results in this micro optimization it would worth adding possessive quantifiers

Comment: I liked *shit* version more.

Comment: @VisioN: I don't want to offend anyone. SO is sensitive.

Comment: @Lindrian: http://ideone.com/gcxKm7 (but, yes, js doesn't support possessive quantifiers)

Comment: @zerkms: Whats your point? The second example in your test takes up a lot of time as you have shown -- but it does not match, ever.

Comment: @Lindrian: 1nd and 2nd taken from the original question as is. 3rd - yours. 4th - yours with possessive quantifiers. My point: it's possible to get it even better ;-)

Answer (score 4):

Not sure about your performance problem (if any) but you can use a single regex to extract both values:

```
var str = '[John Smith] <johnsmith@gmail.com>',
    re = /\[(.+)\] <(.+)>/,
    name = str.match( re )[1],
    email = str.match( re )[2];

console.log( name, email ); //=> "John Smith johnsmith@gmail.com"
```

Answer (score 3):

This is due to the use of many greedy `.*`s combined with fact the string has the form `"[..] <..>"`.

Every time you use `.*` without a `?`, the RegExp engine selects the rest of the whole string then move backwards a character at a time as the following parts of the RegExp fail, testing the next part.

As you have repeated `.*`s, this means you're telling it to run exponentially more tests for each character back from the end of the string that the RegExp engine has to backtrack. It's then made even worse by the greedy `+` signs, repeating what the `*` is doing all over again.

Just adding in `?`s is not the best fix here as you know more about the string and you're not looking for that much within it. Therefore to make it less *"bad"*, do something such as matching only the bit you're interested in

```
var re1 = /\<([^>]*)>/,
    re2 = /\[([^\]]*)\]/;

var address = email.match(re1)[1],
    uname = email.match(re2)[1]; // to avoid `window.name` conflict
```